# Terminal File replace testA with a

Tags: sed, terminal

Is there a way to convert `testThatMy` to `thatMy` using the Terminal?

This is what I have now:

`sed -i 's/test//g' MyJavaFile.java`

The only thing missing would be to convert the character after `test` now to lower case.

Also for some reason referencing to a regex variable does not seem to work.

`sed -i 's/test([A-Z]{1})/\1/g' MyJavaFile.java`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following GNU sed command:

```
sed -r 's/test([[:upper:]])([^[:space:]]*)/\L\1\2/g' file.java
```

For in place editing you need to pass `-i`, but I would test the command first.

Pattern Explanation:

- `-r` enables extended POSIX regular expressions.
- `[[:upper:]]` matches an uppercase character
- `[^[:space:]]*` matches zero or more non space characters

Replacement Explanation:

- `\L` transform the following expression to uppercase. `\1` is the content first capturing group. `\2` is the content of the second capturing group.

Comment: Thanks. Though I had to change it to `'s/test(([[:upper:]])[^[:space:]]*)/\L\1/g'`